# How to store optional information MySql

Tags: mysql

In my application users can order gift cards. They can select how they want to be delivered: via mail of via email. Those two delivery methods require different information for example the via email method requires only the recipients email and the other first name last name address country city postal etc. I am wondering what's the best way to store those data. Currently I am storing the data like that

```
orders
    delivery_method field (via_mail, via_email) 
    recipient_email (nullable required when delivery_method is via email) 
    etc...
shipping_addresses (optional relationship required when delivery_method is via mail)
    order_id 
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    city 
    etc...
```

Seems a bit inconsistent to me especially when based on the delivery method those data need to be present. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Would it be possible for the same customer to place more than one order?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes they can place any number of orders they want.

Comment: 1 order, multiple recipients? Mixed shipping methods?

Comment: 1 order 1 recipient that might be different than the purchaser account. Two ways to deliver to the recipient one via post one via email

Comment: So customers are missing from your schema. Shipping addresses would be independent or depend from the customer.  An order would refer to a shipping address iso the other way round.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes I didn't include customers here since they are not really part of my problem. Shipping address is only related to the order. The case is I the customer place an order for a gift that I can ship it to another person or email it.

Comment: And next year, when the customer wants to send the same gift to the same beneficiary, you'll register the same address again?

Comment: Well yes if the customer buys a gift card again. You think that this poses a problem?

Comment: Normally, with RDB's, the intention is to avoid repeating the same information.  One address, one record.  It would also be more user-friendly, if the customer could reuse previous addresses.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes I agree even if there is no business requirement here that can be easily solved by reverting the relationship of the address and the order. But still doesn't answer my question which is how can I ensure that the data that the order holds are the ones that the delivery method requires? It's my first question here sorry if it's a bit confusing :)

Comment: In my experience, the email address will mostly be the customers.  If an order is for a physical gift card, it must be linked to a shipping address, otherwise it mustn't.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you need to `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` individual mail columns (`first_name`, `city`, etc), so why bother having columns for them.  Instead have two columns:

```
mechanism ENUM('email', 'mail') NOT NULL,
address TEXT NOT NULL,
```

The address for an email would be short:  `"john.doe@example.com"` and longer for mail:  `"John Doe\n124 Main St.\nLincoln, Maine 01234\nUSA"`.

Then, make sure that you use or interpret "newlines" when formatting envelopes.

For the user, you might prompt with a `<textarea>`, letting them provide the newlines as appropriate for mailing.  That is, there is very little work for you -- even less than having lots of separate columns for the pieces of an address.